# How to display folium marker on google colab?

Tags: python-3.x, geospatial, google-colaboratory, folium

I am working on Chicago crime dataset and using google colab.
I have done clustering now I want to show cluster on folium map using different colors.
But the problem is that it is not showing any circle markers. I got no errors or warning.
I know that folium cannot handle very large data that's why I am trying to map only 500 location.
Can anyone tell me what's wrong??
Below are the code and its output on colab.
df2 contains 500 rows and columns name you can see in the image below.

[image]

Comment: Please add code as well as the link to the data. We can't help you until you show us some code.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my folium example notebook.

https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1AZXs7vQGmHkXnxdeiVCrP6NKG3eMVkLc

CircleMarker works fine here.